# How do I save and multiple objects from a single file?

Tags: java, android, objectinputstream

I want my app to store multiple objects locally for later use.

Now, my problem is that I know how to load an object from an `ObjectInputStream` by taking the entire file(federations.dat). Is there a way for me to load say `object WHERE id = N` from "federations.dat" ? Or do I have to create separate files for each object?

This is my load method:

```
public static Object load(Context ctx, String filename) throws FileNotFoundException 
{
    Object loadedObj = null;
    InputStream instream = null;

    instream = ctx.openFileInput(filename);

    try {
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(instream);
        loadedObj = ois.readObject();
        return loadedObj;
        
    } catch (StreamCorruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Any suggestions come to mind ?

Comment: From android application, you can save into it Database http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An extention to @Jan 's code, fixing the problem of keeping `ois` open if an exception is thrown, along with some minor issues.

```
public static ArrayList<Object> load(Context ctx, String filename) throws FileNotFoundException {
    InputStream instream = ctx.openFileInput(filename);

    ArrayList<Object> objects = new ArrayList<Object>();

    try {
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(instream);
        try{
            Object loadedObj = null;
            while ((loadedObj = ois.readObject()) != null) {
                objects.add(loadedObj);
            }

            return objects;
        }finally{
            ois.close();
        }

    } catch (StreamCorruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use it like this..

```
ArrayList<Object> arrayList = new ArrayList<Object>();

Object obj = null;

while ((obj = ois.readObject()) != null) {
    arrayList.add(obj);
}
```

You can return an ArrayList on your method.

```
return arrayList;
```

Edit:
Full code would be like this..

```
public static ArrayList<Object> load(Context ctx, String filename) 
{
    InputStream fis = null;
    ObjectInputStream ois = null;

    ArrayList<Object> arrayList = new ArrayList<Object>();

    Object loadedObj = null;
    try {
        fis = ctx.openFileInput(filename);
        ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);

        while ((loadedObj = ois.readObject()) != null) {
             arrayList.add(loadedObj);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    } finally {
        if (null != ois) ois.close();
        if (null != fis) fis.close();
    }

    return arrayList;
}
```

Hope it helps..

Comment: If I'm not mistaken this leaves ois open when an exception is thrown. My OOP class advocated the use of two nested tries, the outer one catches the exception, the inner one only has a finally which closes ois.

Comment: It would be.. I just did required edit on @litemode's code. It is a problem which the developer has to solve. But it was a good catch anyway..

Comment: Also, it appears that the first time you read an object from ois, it is discarded.