# Save an object or list of objects in Android

Tags: android

I have a list of a custom object class that I called Students, and I would like to save it in a way such that it won't be affected when we close the app completely. The class: (of course I have a constructor and stuff, but these are the fields that may be important)

```
public class Students implements Serializable{
private int ID;
private int imageId;
private String firstName;
private String lastName;
private Map<Date, Boolean> Attendance;
```

My attempt in saving and reading it (inside an activity):

```
public Boolean saveStudent(Students s) {//saves student into fileName (data.bin)
    ObjectOutputStream oos = null;
    try {
        File file = new File(this.getFilesDir().toString(), fileName);
        file.createNewFile();
        if(!file.mkdir()){ //just to check whats the reason behind the failed attempt
            Toast.makeText(this, "Security Issue", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        FileOutputStream fos = this.openFileOutput(fileName, this.MODE_PRIVATE);
        oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
        oos.writeObject(s);
        oos.close();
        fos.close();
        return true;
    } catch (FileNotFoundException err) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Something went wrong while saving", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return false;
    } catch (Exception abcd) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Ooops, I don't know what's the problem. Sorry about that!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return false;
    }
    finally {//makes sure to close the ObjectOutputStream
        if (oos != null) {
            try {
                oos.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}


public Students readStudent() {//reads Student object from(data.bin) and returns it.
    ObjectInputStream ois = null;
    try {
        ois = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("data.bin"));
        ois.close();
        return (Students) ois.readObject();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    } finally {
        if (ois != null) {
            try {
                ois.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

When I run, it gives me the "Something went wrong while saving" and "Security Issue". Can some one help me solve this problem?

PS: I really don't wanna use an SQLlite database because I think that it's an overkill for just 3 or 4 entries. I hope it's not one of those stupid mistakes that take several hours of staring to find out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check this source. I have tested it, and it is working well.

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Students students = new Students();
        students.setID(1234);
        students.setFirstName("hello");
        Log.d("test", "pre students="+students);
        saveStudent(students);

        Students s = readStudent();
        Log.d("test", "after students="+s);

    }

    String fileName = "data.bin";

    public Boolean saveStudent(Students s) {//saves student into fileName (data.bin)
        ObjectOutputStream oos = null;
        try {
           /* File file = new File(this.getFilesDir().toString(), fileName);
            file.createNewFile();
            if(!file.mkdir()){ //just to check whats the reason behind the failed attempt
                Toast.makeText(this, "Security Issue", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }*/
            FileOutputStream fos = this.openFileOutput(fileName, this.MODE_PRIVATE);
            oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
            oos.writeObject(s);
            oos.close();
            fos.close();
            return true;
        } catch (FileNotFoundException err) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Something went wrong while saving", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return false;
        } catch (Exception abcd) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Ooops, I don't know what's the problem. Sorry about that!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return false;
        }
        finally {//makes sure to close the ObjectOutputStream
            if (oos != null) {
                try {
                    oos.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }


    public Students readStudent() {//reads Student object from(data.bin) and returns it.
        ObjectInputStream ois = null;
        Students students = new Students();
        try {
            /*ois = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("data.bin"));*/
            ois = new ObjectInputStream(openFileInput(fileName));
            students = (Students) ois.readObject();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        } finally {
            if (ois != null) {
                try {
                    ois.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        return students;
    }
}
```

And for saving and loading multiple objects, please check this link [How do I save and multiple objects from a single file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11257667/how-do-i-save-and-multiple-objects-from-a-single-file)

Comment: Shouldn't they save on the internal storage which doesn't require any permissions?

Comment: Update: I have just added: <uses-permission android:name="WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>, and nothing happened. The problem still exists :( , Thanks anyways :D

Comment: Sorry, you don't need to add these permissions. please remove **File file = new File(this.getFilesDir().toString(), fileName);
        file.createNewFile();
        if(!file.mkdir()){ //just to check whats the reason behind the failed attempt
            Toast.makeText(this, "Security Issue", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }**. You don't need these codes if you write "openFileOutput".

Comment: "Security Issue" occurred because you called **file.mkdir()**. **file** was already created as "file", but you tried to create it as "directory" again so the error occurred. And openFileOuput can create new file if not exist, you don't need all the above codes that I said.

Comment: I just did what you suggested, and the errors are gone. However in the onCreate method, i have "File f = new File(this.getFilesDir().toString()+fileName);" and if f doesn't exist toast -> "File doen't exist" else toast "File exist". It is always giving me the File doesn't exit.

Comment: Please print **this.getFilesDir().toString()+fileName** for test using Log.d. What does it show?

Comment: /data/user/0/com.example.mohammadel_ghali.attendance/filesdata.bin

Comment: I guess it should have a "/" before data.bin right :P

Comment: Update: I added the "/" as in " File f = new File(this.getFilesDir().toString()+"/"+fileName)"

Comment: It is now working (saving part -> no errors), but when I login (reading part), it is crashing. Is there something wrong with the reading part(found in the code above)?

Comment: Please modify some code in readStudent() method as the following. **ois = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("data.bin"));** to **ois = new ObjectInputStream( openFileInput("data.bin"););**

Comment: Man thanks for helping out. I really appreciate it :D. Unfortunately, the app is crashing still : "Process: com.example.mohammadel_ghali.attendance, PID: 24224
                                                                                         java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object reference
                                                                                             at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:409)......"

Comment: Please show all error log. it was insufficient.^^ What value did "String java.lang.Object.toString()" have?

Comment: Is it possible to skype with you just to avoid long conversation here? if yes, please call me at  mohammad_ghali (<--Skype username). That would really help me :D.

Comment: I think you have to remove **ois.close();** above **return (Students) ois.readObject();** in removeStudent method. Before you call readObject, you don't have to close the inputstream.^_^; Anyway, please let me know if you need any help.^^~

Comment: Hey again, yeah I noticed. I fixed my messed up syntax, but now it is saving (i hope so :p), but when it is reading, I am getting problems. See, I am saving every "Students" in a Students [] alone, and I am trying to read them back again.

Comment: ois = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(new File(this.getFilesDir().toString()+"/"+fileName)));
            Students[] temp =  new Students[8];
            for(int i=0;i<8;i++){
                temp[i]=(Students) ois.readObject();
            }
            ois.close();
            return temp;

Comment: it is giving me exceptions, but I printed the array in Log.D -->[null,null,null.......]

Comment: Hi. I added the source I tested above. It is possible to save just one Students object, so you have to change some codes for saving multiple Students objects.

Comment: Hi again, yeah thanks it worked! Apparently, I had to delete the app and reinstall it. I feel so dumb :P. Thanks again :D

Comment: Good luck! ^^ @M.Ghali

Answer (score 0):

No need to `file.mkdir()`

Give `openFileOutput` an absolutePath may be good.

Check here:

```
File file = new File(this.getFilesDir().toString(), fileName);
file.createNewFile();
//if(!file.mkdir()){ //just to check whats the reason behind the failed attempt
//    Toast.makeText(this, "Security Issue", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//}
// Use file.getAbsolutePath()
FileOutputStream fos = this.openFileOutput(file.getAbsolutePath(), this.MODE_PRIVATE);
oos =oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
oos.writeObject(s);
oos.close();
fos.close();
return true;
```

And in the read method you should give an absolute file path

check this line : `ois = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("data.bin"));`

pass more information to the `new FileInputStream("data.bin")`

change to :`new FileInputStream(new File(getContext().getFilesDir(),"data.bin"));`

Do not forget the parent dir.

Comment: The errors are now gone. However in the onCreate method, i have "File f = new File(this.getFilesDir().toString()+fileName);" and if f doesn't exist toast -> "File doen't exist" else toast "File exist". It is always giving me the File doesn't exit.

Comment: Hi @M.Ghali  Try `File f = new File(this.getFilesDir().toString()+ File.seperator + fileName);` or `File f = new File(this.getFilesDir(), fileName);`

Comment: hello, it worked now, and the file exists and everything is great. However, when it is reading the file, the app is crashing: "Process: com.example.mohammadel_ghali.attendance, PID: 24224 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object reference at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdap‌​ter.java:409)......"

Comment: I guess the `readStudent()` returns NULL. I edited my answer just now